# Word for "take with permission but no intention of returning"

Tags: single-word-requests

In such cases, "borrow" doesn't fit, as it implies intent to return, nor does "steal", which indicates lack of permission. "take" seems too general.

As a concrete example: "Hey, can I [verb] some painkillers?"

Comment: *Have* would fit the request.

Comment: "Hey, do you have any painkillers to spare?", followed by "I owe you one, thank you!".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Andrew writes in his comment, the most natural choice would probably be *have*. I’m not sure why you think *take* is too general, either: it accurately describes what happens.

Another option you might consider, though it is quite colloquial, would be *snatch*:

> Man, I’ve got a splittin’ headache … all right with you if I snatch a couple of painkillers from your stash?

*Snatch* usually means ‘steal’, but it is frequently used in colloquial speech to refer to taking something (with no intention of giving it back), but without any reference to whether you’ve obtained permission or not.

Of course, in the context of your example, logic and normal expectations would override almost any verb, and even *borrow* could be used without anyone think that the headache-ridden would ever intend or be expected to actually give back the painkillers after they’d passed through his system.

Comment: And of course, the sufferer might return the favour, so *borrow* could still be useful (but it wouldn't be the **same** tablets).

Comment: Mostly I'm trying to preempt snarky "borrow? what, are you going to give them back?" comments.

Comment: In that case, if you want to remain neutral and not overly colloquial or slangy, just go with _take_ or _have_. The simplest solution is often the easiest, and there’s no need, really, for the verb to unambiguously specify both that you’re taking the pills with permission _and_ that you don’t intend to return them. Both would be naturally inferred unless you use a verb that specifically overrides either. (And if you’d just gone and taken some without bothering to come on here and ask, your headache would be gone by now. :-þ)

Comment: It isn't clear whether an element of deception is involved here which would possibly inform the term chosen.

Answer (score 2):

You could say, "Hey, can you spare a couple aspirin?" You're really asking for a FAVOR, not a loan.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the answer you're seeking is "mooch"

verb (used with object)

1. to borrow (a small item or amount) without intending to return or repay it.
2. to get or take without paying or at another's expense; sponge: He always mooches cigarettes.
3. to beg.
4. to steal.

Comment: Hi, welcome to EL&U! This is a great first answer. Is the definition yours? If not, it would be even better if you could include a citation for and link to the source. Nothing fancy, just, say, "M-W" if it's Merriam-Webster or "Oxford Dictionaries" etc. with a link to the particular definition. You can use the edit link right below your answer to make any desired changes.